# определение пути к файлу gradle.build по его вызову

Tags: gradle

Доброго времени суток. У меня есть следующая иерархия файлов в проекте

```
messages/  
-build.gradle  
-settings.gradle  
-consumer/  
--build.gradle  
-producer/  
--build.gradle
```

В файле *settings.gradle*:

```
include 'consumer', 'producer'
```

Я хочу выполнить определенные действия, когда я вызываю команду *gradle build* в каталоге *consumer* и какие-нибудь другие действия, если я вызываю эту команду из каталога *производитель*. Как узнать, из какого каталога вызывается команда *gradle build*? Или, может быть, вы знаете другой подход для решения этой проблемы. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Как то так (писал на коленках, так что возможно требуется отладка):

```
def getCurrentDir = { ->
   return file('.').toString();
}

buildscript {
  //blah-blah
  def dir=getCurrentDir();
  println(dir); //печать на консоль
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но есть один нюанс в работе gradle. Сейчас объясню. Дело в том, что при вызове команды gradle build не важно откуда, после этого грэдл сразу лезет в файл settings.gradle, потом в файл gradle.build, а потом исходя из настроек файла settings.gradle опрашивает другие файлы gradle.build в подпроектах (по умолчанию в алфавитном порядке). Поэтому ваш вариант не пройдет, так как в этом случае всегда будет возвращаться корневая папка, а не подпапка. Может, есть другие идеи?)  Может, как-то можно уже средствами java или groovy как-то определить из какого места был вызван процесс?

Comment: Ну дык, вставьте код в `build.gradle`, которые в подпапках, что он тогда вернет?

Comment: Возвращает все равно корневую директорию. Решение я описал выше)

Answer (score 0):

Да, лучше использовать джавововский метод. Если в файле settings.gradle написать следующие две функции, возвращающие текущий каталог:

```
println ('path where gradle.build was called: ' + file('build.gradle').getParentFile().getName())

println ('another variant of path: ' + System.getProperty("user.dir"))
```

,то первая функция (функция gradle) вернет корневую папку, а вторая функция (функция java) вернет именно ту папку, откуда была вызвана команда, то есть откуда начался сам процесс.